# ffmpeg extract subtitles with unknown codec

Tags: c#, .net-framework, video, ffmpeg, gps

I'm writing a program which extracts images and GPS coordinates from files that were created by car video recorder.
In many models it creates two separate files Video and GPS but not all, some  recorders write information about GPS – coordinates into video file subtitles. So I Faced with the problem of extracting subtitles from video file.
Using such command

```
d:\test\ffmpeg -i "d:\test\example_1.MOV" -an -vn -c:s copy -f rawvideo  d:\test\sub.txt
```

I got subtitles from file "example_1.MOV", but with another file "example_2.MOV" I got a message "Output file #0 does not contain any stream"
Full log is:

```
    d:\test\ffmpeg -i "d:\test\example_2.MOV"  -an -vn -codec:s copy -f rawvideo d:\test\sub2.txt
ffmpeg version N-56575-g21f6ff3 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep 22 2013 18:02:01 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 46.100 / 52. 46.100
  libavcodec     55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavformat    55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 87.100 /  3. 87.100
  libswscale      2.  5.100 /  2.  5.100
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'd:\test\example_2.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2014-03-30 16:05:10
    comment         : RELLA A7L
    comment-pra     : RELLA A7L
  Duration: 00:02:34.72, start: 0.033367, bitrate: 9039 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280
x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9014 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (de
fault)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-30 16:05:10
      handler_name    : Ambarella AVC
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
8 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-30 16:05:10
      handler_name    : Ambarella AAC
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (RVMI / 0x494D5652), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    :  GPS and G-Sensor
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'd:\test\sub2.txt':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    comment-pra     : RELLA A7L
    comment         : RELLA A7L
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

I know exactly that this file has a subtitles so I tried to figure out what streams does this file contain using command

```
d:\Test\ffprobe -show_streams -i "d:\test\example_2.MOV"
```

i got such information

```
d:\test\ffprobe -show_streams -i "d:\test\example_2.
MOV"
ffprobe version N-64836-gce385c8 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 20 2014 23:42:59 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-lib
modplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinge
r --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --en
able-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis
 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-
libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 92.101 / 52. 92.101
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 48.101 / 55. 48.101
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.102 /  4. 11.102
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'd:\test\example_2.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2014-03-30 16:05:10
    comment         : RELLA A7L
    comment-pra     : RELLA A7L
  Duration: 00:02:34.72, start: 0.033367, bitrate: 9039 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280
x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9014 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (de
fault)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-30 16:05:10
      handler_name    : Ambarella AVC
      encoder         : Ambarella AVC encoder
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
8 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-30 16:05:10
      handler_name    : Ambarella AAC
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (RVMI / 0x494D5652), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    :  GPS and G-Sensor
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=Main
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1001/60000
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1280
height=720
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuvj420p
level=31
color_range=pc
color_space=unknown
timecode=N/A
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=30000/1001
avg_frame_rate=30000/1001
time_base=1/30000
start_pts=-1001
start_time=-0.033367
duration_ts=4638634
duration=154.621133
bit_rate=9014524
max_bit_rate=N/A
nb_frames=4634
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:creation_time=2014-03-30 16:05:10
TAG:language=eng
TAG:handler_name=Ambarella AVC
TAG:encoder=Ambarella AVC encoder
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=unknown
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/48000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=7421952
duration=154.624000
bit_rate=128000
max_bit_rate=N/A
nb_frames=7248
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:creation_time=2014-03-30 16:05:10
TAG:language=eng
TAG:handler_name=Ambarella AAC
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=2
codec_name=unknown
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=unknown
codec_type=data
codec_time_base=0/1
codec_tag_string=RVMI
codec_tag=0x494d5652
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/50
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=7736
duration=154.720000
bit_rate=255
max_bit_rate=N/A
nb_frames=309
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:language=eng
TAG:handler_name= GPS and G-Sensor
[/STREAM]
```

So ffmpeg does't want to extract subtitles from this file.
I'd be glad for any suggestions how to extract subtitles from video

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: Done. After "Full log is:"